# how to connect c# windows form with remote mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to connect my server pc MySQL database with client pcs. I make configurations in xampp server. PHPMyAdmin shares with fine in other client pcs. but I run my c# form it gets connection name error. this is my connectiondb class in c# form.

```
 public static MySqlConnection conString()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"server=http://192.168.8.102; userid=root; password=0713; database=pos_system; port=3306");
        return conn;
    }
```

I try to run my application using a client pc but it shows this name cannot find. how to fix my error. I also open firewall port 3306.

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: Why do you have `http://`?

Comment: yes. mysql database shows me on my client pc

Comment: but c# connection not working

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string format is not correct for MySql, try something like this:

```
var con = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=192.168.8.102;Port=3306;Database=pos_system;Uid=root;Pwd=0713;");
```

For more information check:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: i done this. but it shows "cannot find your name" error

Comment: This doesn't really get to the root cause of the problem. Although it's relevant, it's also clear that the server is invalid.

Comment: it seems inappropriate to include http:// in the connection string. You are not trying to connect to the DB using HTTP protocol. You want to connect using the MySQL protocol. So just type the ip without http://

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga I edited my answer and removed the `http` in the connection string you may want to try it again